# Is there a way to add all languages to optimized RequireJS project?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, requirejs, amd, r.js

I have support for two languages in my project (english and spanish). The thing is, that when I optimize the code with r.js, the output file has the root language (english) embed, but not the other variants (spanish).

How can I force the optimizer to embed all the languages on the output file?

Example:

```
// /app/app.js
define(["i18n!nls/something"], function(somethingLanguage) { /* stuff */ });

// /app/nls/something.js
define({
    "root": {
        "hi": "Hi!"
    },
    "es": true
});

// /app/nls/es/something.js
define({
    "hi": "¡Hola!"
});

// /app/result-file.js
define("nls/something", { "hi": "Hi!" });define(["i18n!nls/something"], function(somethingLanguage) { /* stuff */ });
```

As you can see, the "nls/es/something" is missing from the "result-file". It should look like this:

```
// /app/result-file.js
define("nls/something", { "hi": "Hi!" });define("nls/es/something", { "hi": "¡Hola!" });define(["i18n!nls/something"], function(somethingLanguage) { /* stuff */ });
```

I hope you can help me, guys.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue with an extra configuration in r.js:

```
config: {
    "i18n": {
        locale: "es"
    }
}
```

Hope it helps others with the same issue.